# Adding custom subviews to NSOutlineView with source list style

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsoutlineview, nsscrollview

I'd like to add some controls above the contents of an `NSOutlineView` that has `NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList` set so that it looks like a Finder/iTunes/iPhoto-like source list. The controls I want to add should therefore be placed above the whole source list, but in the same `NSScrollView` as the outline view. The color behind them should also be that of the source lis (which is special because it changes from light blue to grey when the window loses focus).

I already tried to move the `NSOutlineView` down programmatically inside its parent views (which are a `NSClipView` and then an `NSScrollView`), but changing the `NSOutlineView`s frame doesn't work (the frame isn't changed at all).

Cheers

MrMage

Comment: Have you by any chance set an autoresizing mask on your outline view?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you're trying to achieve? An outline view that looks like the Finder or iTunes source lists is possible without mucking about with the scroll view at all. Have a look at Apple's [SourceView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SourceView/) example.

Comment: I would like to add controls *above* the outline view that neverthelesss are on the same blue-ish colored background and that are in the *same* scroll area as the outline view. That's not so simple as it seems.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing -- controls sharing the background color of a source list but higher than (above, not on-top of) the content -- is not at all similar to Finder or iTunes.  They put controls in the window's toolbar space.  In fact, what you describe sounds like a poor UI decision entirely.

That said, you could probably achieve your stated goal by adding one or more rows of "empty content" i.e. return `nil` from `outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:byItem:` and possibly set custom row height with `outlineView:heightOfRowByItem:` and then add your subviews onto that "empty" space.